# Emmet for Sublime Text 3 Custom Snippets

Tags: html, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext, emmet

I am learning to create custom html snippets for Emmet. The first snippet I would like create is an html script element to a jQuery CDN. I've spent over an hour scouring the [Emmet documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/), searching with Google, and searching Stack Overflow.

This is the result I'm looking for:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is what I've entered in Emmet.sublime-settings file:

```js
{
  "variables": {
    "jqCdn": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
  },
  "snippets": {
    "html": {
      "snippets": {
        // jq abbreviations
        "jq": "script:src[${jqCdn}]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"script:src=[jqCdn]" is produced when I type "jq" and press the tab key. The file I'm attempting to use the code in has nothing in it and I've saved it as temp.html.

I've also tried using the same syntax swapping out jqCdn variable for the full url. This produces a similar result:

> "script:src=[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js]"

I've tried entering the full plain text for the desired html script element at the "jq" snippet. This method works. However, I wish to learn how to use the variable and Emmet abbreviations (if possible) for easier maintenance of my snippets as my list of custom snippets grows.